# .htaccess redirect www conflict other rules

Tags: .htaccess

Hello im trying to redirect non www to www. Usually i get it with this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But i have this on my htaccess so i get problems.

```
# SEO URL Settings

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index.php(.*)$ index.php$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/*$ index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/find/(.+)$ index.php?_route_=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^find/(.+)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/admin(/*)$ admin/index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/admin(.*)$ admin/$2
```

I know i just have to add www to that rules (maybe) ihave tried with no luck =(

Problems:

i should get www.example.com/user1/ or www.example.com/user2/ and i get www.example.com/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/ error

it works great just in this case example.com to www.example.com

I also cant login into the admin example.com/admin/ redirects to the same URL with www but i never login =(

SOLUTION:
:::::::::

I add this

```
# REDIRECT HTTP://WWW TO HTTP://.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Its working great found it here.: `http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=57274`

HOpe anyone can tell me how to invert the last RULE i just added

so ALL the pages have www.

Comment: i should get www.example.com/user1/ or www.example.com/user2/ and i get www.example.com/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/user1/ error 

it works great just in this case example.com to www.example.com

I also cant login into the admin example.com/admin/ redirects to the same URL with www but i never login =(

Comment: Everything looks fine. Add **L** flag to the first rule, like this: [L,R=301] and see what happens. The other rules should have the [L] flag too.

Comment: Ok it almost work.. the problem is example.com/user1/  now redirects to example.com/mainhome/ =(  and now i cant browse anything in my products all products take me to example.com/mainhome/

Comment: I just solve it .. the answer is on the edited message.. but how can i invert that rule!! pls check

Comment: ¿How would be inverted? Please give an example of the incoming and mapped URLs, the way you want them now.

Comment: I did it, i made your changes they worked, almost! but im not able to login into my admin , thanks very much for your help really apreciate